# How do we know that word of the torah has been kept the same over generations?

Tags: history, pentateuch-chumash

Can we guarantee this text has not been significantly altered in any way? What is the evidence which supports its preservation?

Comment: Please define "significantly". As it is now different Jews have different texts by a handful of letters. Is that significant or not? There are arguments about a handful of dot and cantillations. Is that significant? Parsha breaks?

Comment: Significant in this context would refer to adding in events that were not written in the previous writings, and things of that nature.